# Is cached data being stored for all users the same or different for individual user?

Tags: php, caching, yii2, memcached

Working with Yii Framework 2, I have a dynamic web content which data is changed based on the IP of the user. I configure my cache component as following.

```
'cache' => [
     'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
     'keyPrefix' => 'myDomainName',
     'defaultDuration' => 86400, // The cache will last for 86400 seconds = 1 day
 ],
```

I implement Cache with ActiveRecord as following.

```
$dependency = new \yii\caching\DbDependency(['sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop WHERE ip = ' . $ip]);

$result = Shop::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use($ip) {
    return Shop::find()->where(['ip' => $ip])->all();
}, 86400, $dependency);
```

In fact, each user will see different content based on his IP. This is the first time I try to implement Cache on a website. My question is, will the cache be stored for each user individually or will the cache of one user override the cache of another? Note that from the above code, the DbDependency is also dynamic based on the IP of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Cache data is the same for every part of the application. If you want to 'remember' data for a user you can use the session. In the session you can store per user data. When the session is closed the data will be gone.

Take a look at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

Comment: This is a good solution. But I found another solution by using cache, yet for a user individually. Cache works with key. Thus, I get data by user_id and use this user_id as the cache key. By doing this, I can store many caches with different key and each cache is for one user. Am I correct?